# Angular - Jasmine error with two 'beforeEach'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Here's my code:

```
var candidateProfile = angular.module('CandidateProfile', ["ngMessages", "validation.match", "rzModule", "ngImgCrop",   "ngLoadingSpinner", "ui.bootstrap"]);


candidateProfile.controller("CandidateProfileController", ['$scope', 'ProfileService', 'MiscService', 'authService', '$filter', 'Flash', 
function($scope, ProfileService, MiscService,authService, $filter, Flash){
//...
}

}]);
```

And my spec file:

```
describe('Test Profile Controller', function(){
 var $scope, ctrl;

 beforeEach(module('CandidateProfile'));

 beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
    //Empty just to verify, had more code before
 }));

 it("should pass", function(){
    expect(true).toBe(true);
 });
});
```

The problem is that karma fails if I have the two 'beforeEach' like this. If I comment one or another, the test passes. Altough, having both causes it to fail with 'Error(native) (//some lines...) at object.workFn (angular-mocks.js).

Any clue about this? I'm sure it may be my problem , I just don't see it..

Answer (score 0):

It is probably dependency related on the module.

The fix should be to declare each of the dependent modules (in another `beforeEach` or just add to the first existing one you have). Note the dependent ones have to have "angular" in front of them.

```
angular.module('ngMessages', []);
```

Read through the //some lines that you omitted and see if you can tell which one is missing. You don't always need them all but usually you do.